# <%%> onserverclick ignores server method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

I rendered an `<a>` in HTML from code behind and from HTML page. however, from HTML side is works properly and from the server side, it doesn't recognize the method!
id = Try21 is from HTML side.
id= Try1 from server side
HTML code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <%=LetsSee %>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="gigigg" runat="server" onserverclick="try12" id="Try21" >server click </a>
    <label id="llabel1" runat="server"></label>
    <asp:Label ID="Labek1" runat="server"></asp:Label>     
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />      
</form>
```

code behind:

```
public static string LetsSee = "<a href=\"#as\" runat=\"server\" onserverclick=\"try12\" id=\"Try1\" >server click </a>";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = llabel1.InnerText;
    llabel1.InnerText = "";
    Labek1.Text = "";
}
protected void try12(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    llabel1.InnerText = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor)sender).InnerHtml;
    Labek1.Text = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor)sender).InnerHtml;
}
```

I created 2 `<a>` one from server side and one from HTML side both with the same onserverclick to the same method however the HTML one works and the server one doesn't, my question is how to make the server one work?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking, but I can tell you that all rendering takes place server-side.

Comment: i created 2 <a> one from server side and one from HTML side both with the same onserverclick to the same method however the HTML one works and the server one doesn't, my question is how to make the server one work

Comment: I don't see that you wired up the handler. See [the second example on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: i dont need to since it has runat=server it can access methods from server side. however when I load the page and the HTML <a> and the server <a> are generated' only the HTML's onserverclick works!

Comment: It has been a long time, but I think the one that works is because you have auto event wire up turned on. That may not work for OnServerClick. I suggest you try it instead of saying you don't need to, or switch to OnClick instead of OnServerClick.